# Regex to truncate last 4 characters and make sure it doesn't contain specific words

Tags: regex, grafana

I get strings such as "BumpCardV2Resource.getInstance.Time" or "BumpCardWebResource.getInstance.Time" or "BumpCardResource.getInstance.Time". I need a regex expression to obtain only "BumpCardResource.getInstance"

Currently, I'm using a negative look ahead to make sure the string does not contain V2 or Web but not sure how to truncate the last 5 characters (.Time) along with that.

Regex I'm using: `/^(?!.*V2|.*WebResource).*$/`

PS - The resource and the API endpoint keeps changing. It need not be necessarily only BumpCard or getInstance

Comment: With another lookahead? `/^(?!.*V2|.*WebResource).*(?=\.Time$)/`

Comment: I still need the string but just do not need the (.Time) part of it

Comment: So, use what I suggested, https://regex101.com/r/H9JdZw/1 ?

Comment: This regex doesn't seem to be working in Grafana, unfortunately - Where I need it to work :(

Comment: Doesn't it mean `/^(?!.*V2|.*WebResource).*$/` does not work at all either?

Comment: That is working, however. Your regex makes sense. Unsure as to why it is not working though :/

Comment: You should update your question to state what exactly your rules are. What's a resource, and how is it defined? What's an API endpoint and how is it defined?

Comment: Try with a capturing group then, `/^(?!.*V2|.*WebResource)(.*)\.Time$/`

Comment: With grafana you should know when to escape the backslash. Just use the solution by @WiktorStribiżew but remember if you are using double quotes then you must escape the backslash, but if using single quotes, do not escape the backslash

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a regex where you *match the whole string* and *capture* any text from the start of the string till `.Time` at the end of it:

```
/^(?!.*V2|.*WebResource)(.*)\.Time$/
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/H9JdZw/2). *Details*:

- `^` - start of string
- `(?!.*V2|.*WebResource)`  - no `V2` or `WebResource` allowed anywhere in the string
- `(.*)` - **Capturing group 1**: any zero or more chars other than line break chars as many as possible
- `\.Time` - `.Time` string
- `$` - end of string.